# PCManFM-Qt. How to change the background color?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets, pcmanfm

I'd like to change the background color of PCManFM-Qt, the file manager of LxQt. I now a custom stylesheet can be used with the option -stylesheet. I found the program Gammaray, a program similar to gtk-inspector. After some trying I got something working with featherpad. The css code:

```css
#centralWidget{ background-color: red; }
```

works, but I cannot make red the QTextEdit widget. I don't care about featherpad, because I'd like to change the background color of PCManFM-Qt.

Answer (score 0):

Try `QTextEdit { background-color: red; }`, or similiar

Qt has to know the object to which apply  CSS props.

Comment: Already tryed. I think I should pass all the widget hierarchy.

Comment: Like this maybe `* QTextEdit { background-color: red; }`

Comment: Already tryed. I'm not interested in QTextEdit.